# How to re-order labels in a graph? - Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to re-order the labels of my graph.

Currently my graph looks like this:
[image]

As you can see the labels at the bottom are in this order:

'>100k', '<25k', '50-100k', '25-50k'

But I want to reorder them to be displayed like this:

'<25k', '25-50k', '50-100k', '>100k'

which makes much more sense.

I have used this code

```
data.sort_values('$Group', ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

but it doesn't help since the data is not numerical.

Is it possible to re-order the labels?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a custom sort to the financial groups using `pd.Categorical`.  Here is some fake data, with the groups created in the order shown in your plot:

```
earnings = ['>100k', '<25k', '50-100k', '25-50k']
values = [1,5,2,5]
df = pd.DataFrame({'earnings':earnings,
                   'values':values})
# plot here and you get the issue that you observe
# df.plot.bar(x='earnings')
```

Now applying a custom sort on the `earnings` column so that `pandas` will order the data as desired when we call `sort_values()`:

```
df['earnings'] = pd.Categorical(values = df['earnings'],
                                categories=['<25k', '25-50k', '50-100k', '>100k'],
                                ordered=True)
df = df.sort_values('earnings')
df.plot.bar(x='earnings')
```

Result:

[image]